# System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch returns negative numbers in Elapsed... properties

Tags: c#, stopwatch

Is it normal behaviour that Stopwatch can return negative values? Code sample below can be used to reproduce it.

```
 while (true)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            sw.Stop();

            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 0)
                Debugger.Break();

        }
```

The only place where I can reproduce negative numbers is my virtual machine (hosted by Hyper-V on a 8-core machine)

Comment: What is the value of ElapsedMilliseconds when negative?

Comment: Uninstall your flux capacitor.

Comment: It changes every time. It can take several loop spins for negative number to occur.

Comment: I am asking more for the magnitude. Is it usually around -10ms? or is it usually -4000000000ms?

Comment: On my VM it around -3000 to -2000

Comment: The Stopwatch class also returns extremely high values randomly when under a VM environment.

Comment: I get this problem too. The value of my timespan totalmilleseconds comes up as either (around) 4.332 or -23.774

Answer (score 18):

This is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94083&wa=wsignin1.0). It doesn't seem to have a lot of attention around it, through, so I'd suggesting following up with that report.

The [uninspiring workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=94083) appears to be to ignore negative values:

```
long elapsedMilliseconds = Math.Max(0, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: It seems that the only way to reproduce it is to use a virtual machine. 
I've tried the code on several desktop machines - no success

Comment: This work-around only eliminates negative values - it does not eliminate the extremely high (false) positive values it also returns.

Comment: It's working in .NET 4, but is difficult to believe that the bug still exists in .NET 3.5 :(

Comment: It's not completely fixed in .NET 4; see my comments in the Connect report and in my answer...

Answer (score 13):

I decompiled the Stopwatch class in both .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 using Reflector and then compared the differences to see how it was fixed. Besides the addition of the new Restart method, this is all I found for a difference:

```
public void Stop()
{
    if (this.isRunning)
    {
        long num2 = GetTimestamp() - this.startTimeStamp;
        this.elapsed += num2;
        this.isRunning = false;
// THE NEXT 4 LINES ARE NEW IN .NET 4.0:
        if (this.elapsed < 0L)
        {
            this.elapsed = 0L;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically they set elapsed to 0 in the Stop method if the value is negative. There are still bugs IMHO:

1. What if the user reads any of the Elapsed properties before stopping the stopwatch? You might still get a negative value.
2. Resetting to 0 is not correct. *Some* time had to have elapsed, even if it was only a few microseconds!
3. It does nothing to handle the unusually large positive elapsed values that I and others have reported.

**EDIT:**  Unfortunately, #2 and #3 are beyond the power of the .NET Framework:

Here's the core of the problem:  from MSDN on [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) which is the API used by the Stopwatch class:

> On a multiprocessor computer, it should not matter which processor
>   is called. However, you can get different results on different
>   processors due to bugs in the basic input/output system (BIOS) or the
>   hardware abstraction layer (HAL). To specify processor affinity for a
>   thread, use the SetThreadAffinityMask function.

Don't just use .NET 4.0 stopwatch and assume the problem is fixed.  It isn't and they can't do anything about it unless you want them to muck with your thread affinity.  From the Stopwatch class documentation:

> On a multiprocessor computer, it does not matter which processor the
>   thread runs on. However, because of bugs in the BIOS or the Hardware
>   Abstraction Layer (HAL), you can get different timing results on
>   different processors. To specify processor affinity for a thread, use
>   the ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity method.

Answer (score 0):

The "Closed as Fixed" resolution on the [Microsoft Connect Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94083/stopwatch-returns-negative-elapsed-time) must mean that they fixed it in .NET 4. I've run the repro code on my desktop and a VM for several minutes and got no negative values.

Comment: It's not completely fixed in .NET 4; see my comments in the Connect report and in my answer...

Answer (score -1):

The only workaround that I've found to get the correct elapsed time in a VM is (VB):

```
Dim tstart AS DateTime = Now
...executing code...
Dim telapsed = (Now - tstart).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: downvote wasn't me ... but maybe because the `Ticks` property of `DateTime.Now` has not the same resolution as a `Stopwatch` (as far as I recall, the `Ticks` of `DateTime.Now` only get updated each 15ms)

Comment: Note that the `Now` property will jump ahead or forward dramatically during daylight savings time transitions.  It's also much, much slower than `UtcNow`.

Comment: This is compeletely wrong, never use system time to measure code execution time, system time can change due to time synchronization and can be easily changed by user.